# Conjugate subgroups with sufficiently large intersection are equal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $ K_1,K_2 $ be conjugate subgroups of a matrix group $ G $. That is $ K_1=gK_2g^{-1} $ for some $ g \in G $. Suppose that $ K_1\cap K_2 $ is very large in the sense that it is an irreducible subgroup of $ G $. Can we conclude that $ K_1=K_2 $?

For example take $ G=SU(2) $ and suppose that $ K_1,K_2 $ are conjugate (closed) subgroups of $ SU(2) $ and that $ K_1\cap K_2 $ is an irreducible subgroup. Can we conclude that $ K_1=K_2 $?

Something that got me thinking about this is that if $ K_1 \cap K_2 $ is big in the sense that  $ K_1 \cong N_G(K_1\cap K_2) \cong K_2 $ then I think equality holds and moreover $ K_1 = N_G(K_1\cap K_2) = K_2 $

Comment: This appears too vague. What do you mean by "very large"? I know you gave examples but, really, it can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some more example or at least explain how the question occurred to you.

Comment: I think it really depends on the meaning of "very large".  In the case of finite groups, e.g.$|K_1\cap K_2|>\frac12|K_1|$ is sufficient (and it can fail to be true if the intersection is smaller.

Comment: @Shaun the question occurred to me in the context of matrix groups so I'm happy to specialize to that

Comment: Of course not. Try to find examples among discrete subgroups of $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$, say, taking $K_1=PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh very interesting I'll have to think about an example for $ PSL(2,\mathbb{R}) $. Do you have any thoughts about constructing a counterexample for the case $ G $ compact? For example the case $ G=SU(2) $ described in the question?

Comment: You can Galois conjugate corresponding arithmetic examples from $SL(2,R)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you say more about what you mean by Galois conjugate in this context?